# Adjusting external monitor brightness via keyboard

Tags: display, keyboard, macbook-pro

I have `Dell U2515H` that is connected to `MacBook Pro 13' late 13`.

Is it possible to adjust the brightness of the monitor using the keyboard (and 3rd party app for sure) ? **F1** and **F2** aren't working.

Using the monitor's menu is not convenient at all.

Comment: How are you connecting to the screen?

Comment: @Burgi via DisplayPort